# crash after installing nvidea 210 drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, display-driver

hoping someone can help.  Have seen several references to similar problems, but can't seem to find a solution that's worked for me yet.

I've installed a new ASUS GeForce 210 graphics card in a friend's fairly old machine (FOXCONN G33MDHA motherboard).  The machine fired up fine and booted with the standard Windows drivers.  Windows (32bit Vista) detected the 210 and installed the driver.  It rebooted and then got as far as the loading screen before the moniter went onto standby and the machine eventually rebooted to the "failed to start last time" boot menu.

Going into safe mode works fine.  If I uninstall the driver and reboot, everything's fine (until it reinstalls the driver).  I've tried:

- The driver on the disk that came with the card
- The driver that Windows automatically finds
- The driver on the manufacturer's website

All have the same result.

My own graphics card (an AMD one) drops in and works just fine.  Equally, the new card seems fine when I put it in my own machine.

I've tried the following:

- Different, higher-rated power supply (from my machine where the card works)
- Re-seating the card
- Clean install of Vista on a blank hard drive
- Clean install of Windows 7 on a blank hard drive

I get the same behaviour every time.

Any suggestions gratefully received.  Do I just conclude the motherboard and graphics card are incompatible, or is there something obvious I've not thought of?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Its not that strange for a card that is not fully functioning to work without drivers.  The fact its not working in Vista and Windows 7 indicates its a hardware problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response - where would you suggest the hardware fault is?  The card works fine in another machine.  Equally a different card appears OK in this one.  Motherboard?  Chipset?